# Numpy generate binary array with at most N ones

Tags: python, numpy

I can easily create a random binary array in Numpy by doing this

```
random_mask = np.random.randint(0,2, (r, c))
```

But what what I actually want is to set the maximum number of 1s that can be in the array.

For example, if I want a 5,5 binary matrix, I want there to be at most 10 ones randomly placed throughout the matrix, and the rest are 0s.

I was thinking of an approach where I generate the random array like normal, count the number of 1s that are currently placed, and somehow subtracting off the ones I don't need.

I'm wondering if there's already a way to do this  in numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most basic approach I could think of:

```
import numpy as np

def binary_mask_random(r, c, n):
    a = np.zeros((r,c)).flatten()

    for i in range(np.random.randint(0, n+1)):
        x = np.random.randint(0, r*c)
        a[x] = 1

    return a.reshape((r,c))
```

It creates a `1xr*c` array of zeros and fills it with up to `n` `1`s at random positions. Returns a `rxc` array.

Comment: hm yeah this would do the trick - I guess there isn't a built in way to do this in numpy? was trying to avoid loops

Comment: I don't think, that there is a built-in solution, but it may be possible to find a fully vectorized solution

Comment: yeah I’ll play around with it - thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @Carpetfizz Maybe you could also try `np.random.choice([0, 1], (r, c), p=[0.9, 0.1])`, but i'm not exactly sure, if this will *always* give you the exact results you need, because after all, it's just a probability